# jQuery modal not show name after close and open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I create my custom modal window where i show image and that image contain comments and owner name. When i click on some image modal is opened and show big image, author name, comments etc... Problem is when i close current modal and opent it again name does not exist. But first time when i open modal name is there but only when i close that window and opent it again name does not exist. Check screenshots.
I try to debug it with firebook console and GET response return real name but that name is not rendered after closing and opening.

To prview image i use this code:

```
   preview: function() {
        $('body').on('click', '#open-picture-modal', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#photo_preview").show();
            var $this = $(this);
            var guid = $this.data('guid');
            var photo_id = $this.data('id');

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: baseurl + '/photo/preview',
                data: {'photo_id': photo_id},
                success: function(data) {
                    Photo.photo_author_meta(photo_id);
                    $(".pleft").html('<img class="fileUnitSpacer" src="'+ $this.data('href')+data['photo_name']+'">');
                }
            });

            //window.history.pushState(null, null, pic_url);

          //  $(".image-source").attr("src", $this.data('href'));
        });
    },

    // Close image preview modal
    close: function() {
        $("body").on("click", ".close", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#photo_preview').hide();
            $('#photo_preview .pleft').html('empty');
            $('#photo_preview .pright').html('empty');
        });
    },

    // Show photo author meta(name, date created, etc..)
    photo_author_meta: function(pid){
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: baseurl + '/photo/photo_details',
            data: {'post_id': pid},
            success: function(data) {
                $("h4.photo-author-full-name").html(data['account_firstname'] +'&nbsp;'+ data['account_lastname']);
            }
        });
    },
```

And here is modal where i append and set html

```
<div id="photo_preview" style="display:none">
    <div class="photo_wrp">
        <span class="pull-right close fa fa-times"> </span>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="pleft"></div>
        <div class="pright">
            <div class="photo-author-meta">
                <div class="media">
                    <a href="#" class="media-left">
                        <img alt="64x64" data-src="holder.js/64x64" class="media-object" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;" src="test.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body photo-author-name-box">
                        <div class="photo-author-name">
                            <h4 class="media-heading photo-author-full-name"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo-datetime-box">
                            <div class="photo-date-posted"> Objavljeno: </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: On first open][image: After close and again open]

Like u can see on first image i have firstname and lastname in modal.
On second image i open again the some modal but name and surname does not exist. But check firebug console, data exist but not rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various things:

1 - You are messing with .html() and .empty():

```
$('#photo_preview .pleft').html(); // or .empty()
```

2 - As you delete all the content from `#photo_preview .pright`, when you do:

```
$("h4.photo-author-full-name").html(data['account_firstname'] +'&nbsp;'+ data['account_lastname']);
```

This element don't exist. You could create it, or not empty all the div content.

You could change this:

```
$('#photo_preview .pright').html(); // or .empty()
```

to

```
$('h4.photo-author-full-name').html(); // or .empty()
```

In order to no delete the element, only the content on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your close method is removing the HTML that renders the meta data.

```
$('#photo_preview .pright').html('empty');
```

That line is emptying all the HTML within . So, when photo_author_meta() is called a subsequent time after closing, *h4.photo-author-full-name* no longer exists.